# Method reference as an Executor implementation

Tags: java, lambda, runnable, executor, method-reference

I have been studying an example java code written by someone and faced the following snippet:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

Executor executor;

executor = Runnable::run;
executor.execute(runnable);
```

So, I can't figure out how method reference in this case makes it possible to instantiate an Executor and how is it possible to call `execute(Runnable command)` if it was not implemented. In general how does the method reference works in this case behind the curtains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Executor` meets the definition of a functional interface, in that it has one abstract method.  Namely this one:

```
void execute(Runnable command)
```

So what we need in order to implement this functional interface is a method which operates on a Runnable and returns nothing.  `command -> command.run()`, or `Runnable::run` for short, is an example of a method that will do this.

The following three bits of code are equivalent:

```
executor = Runnable::run;

executor = (Runnable command) -> command.run();

executor = new Executor() {
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
}
```